# How to make a YouTube video play automatically on WordPress home page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, video, autoplay

I need to add an action to my CHILD theme (functions.php).

I need it to activate and launch a YouTube video and make it automatically play when a user opens the home page on the website.

I am pretty sure after lots of research that I need to use the (Function Reference/wp enqueue script)

*** ---> **But I am not good enough at PHP to make it happen.**
..

right now I have the javascript (which is below) in my (header.php) file so it will load and make the video play automatically.

but of course this is not good as it plays on every single page every time someone opens it.

here is my testing platform:
http://tonystates.com/

notice how the video loads and play automatically, this is just what we want to happen, but only for the home page.

..

below is my javascript to automatically open the YouTube video and it works.....
*right now it is in the (header.php) file.

(((***But this is the code that we can NOT have in the header.php file as it makes the video play on every page in the site)))
..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.fancybox.open({
type: 'iframe',
href: 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/6muHD6bdDYQ?rel=0&border=&autoplay=1',
width: '70%',
height: '70%'})
    $('.various').fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight    : 600,
        fitToView    : false,
        width        : '70%',
        height        : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick    : false,
        openEffect    : 'none',
        closeEffect    : 'none'

    });

});
```

below is my PARENT theme functions.php code for reference.

```
    <?php
/**
 * Twenty Twelve functions and definitions
 *
 * Sets up the theme and provides some helper functions, which are used
 * in the theme as custom template tags. Others are attached to action and
 * filter hooks in WordPress to change core functionality.
 *
 * When using a child theme (see http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development and
 * http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), you can override certain functions
 * (those wrapped in a function_exists() call) by defining them first in your child theme's
 * functions.php file. The child theme's functions.php file is included before the parent
 * theme's file, so the child theme functions would be used.
 *
 * Functions that are not pluggable (not wrapped in function_exists()) are instead attached
 * to a filter or action hook.
 *
 * For more information on hooks, actions, and filters, @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */

// Set up the content width value based on the theme's design and stylesheet.
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) )
    $content_width = 625;

/**
 * Twenty Twelve setup.
 *
 * Sets up theme defaults and registers the various WordPress features that
 * Twenty Twelve supports.
 *
 * @uses load_theme_textdomain() For translation/localization support.
 * @uses add_editor_style() To add a Visual Editor stylesheet.
 * @uses add_theme_support() To add support for post thumbnails, automatic feed links,
 *  custom background, and post formats.
 * @uses register_nav_menu() To add support for navigation menus.
 * @uses set_post_thumbnail_size() To set a custom post thumbnail size.
 *
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
function twentytwelve_setup() {
    /*
     * Makes Twenty Twelve available for translation.
     *
     * Translations can be added to the /languages/ directory.
     * If you're building a theme based on Twenty Twelve, use a find and replace
     * to change 'twentytwelve' to the name of your theme in all the template files.
     */
    load_theme_textdomain( 'twentytwelve', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

    // This theme styles the visual editor with editor-style.css to match the theme style.
    add_editor_style();

    // Adds RSS feed links to <head> for posts and comments.
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

    // This theme supports a variety of post formats.
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'image', 'link', 'quote', 'status' ) );

    // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
    register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Primary Menu', 'twentytwelve' ) );

    /*
     * This theme supports custom background color and image,
     * and here we also set up the default background color.
     */
    add_theme_support( 'custom-background', array(
        'default-color' => 'e6e6e6',
    ) );

    // This theme uses a custom image size for featured images, displayed on "standard" posts.
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 624, 9999 ); // Unlimited height, soft crop
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twentytwelve_setup' );

/**
 * Add support for a custom header image.
 */
require( get_template_directory() . '/inc/custom-header.php' );

/**
 * Return the Google font stylesheet URL if available.
 *
 * The use of Open Sans by default is localized. For languages that use
 * characters not supported by the font, the font can be disabled.
 *
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.2
 *
 * @return string Font stylesheet or empty string if disabled.
 */
function twentytwelve_get_font_url() {
    $font_url = '';

    /* translators: If there are characters in your language that are not supported
     * by Open Sans, translate this to 'off'. Do not translate into your own language.
     */
    if ( 'off' !== _x( 'on', 'Open Sans font: on or off', 'twentytwelve' ) ) {
        $subsets = 'latin,latin-ext';

        /* translators: To add an additional Open Sans character subset specific to your language,
         * translate this to 'greek', 'cyrillic' or 'vietnamese'. Do not translate into your own language.
         */
        $subset = _x( 'no-subset', 'Open Sans font: add new subset (greek, cyrillic, vietnamese)', 'twentytwelve' );

        if ( 'cyrillic' == $subset )
            $subsets .= ',cyrillic,cyrillic-ext';
        elseif ( 'greek' == $subset )
            $subsets .= ',greek,greek-ext';
        elseif ( 'vietnamese' == $subset )
            $subsets .= ',vietnamese';

        $protocol = is_ssl() ? 'https' : 'http';
        $query_args = array(
            'family' => 'Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,700',
            'subset' => $subsets,
        );
        $font_url = add_query_arg( $query_args, "$protocol://fonts.googleapis.com/css" );
    }

    return $font_url;
}

/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles for front-end.
 *
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 *
 * @return void
 */
function twentytwelve_scripts_styles() {
    global $wp_styles;

    /*
     * Adds JavaScript to pages with the comment form to support
     * sites with threaded comments (when in use).
     */
    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );

    // Adds JavaScript for handling the navigation menu hide-and-show behavior.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwelve-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '1.0', true );

    $font_url = twentytwelve_get_font_url();
    if ( ! empty( $font_url ) )
        wp_enqueue_style( 'twentytwelve-fonts', esc_url_raw( $font_url ), array(), null );

    // Loads our main stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentytwelve-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    // Loads the Internet Explorer specific stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentytwelve-ie', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie.css', array( 'twentytwelve-style' ), '20121010' );
    $wp_styles->add_data( 'twentytwelve-ie', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentytwelve_scripts_styles' );

/**
 * Filter TinyMCE CSS path to include Google Fonts.
 *
 * Adds additional stylesheets to the TinyMCE editor if needed.
 *
 * @uses twentytwelve_get_font_url() To get the Google Font stylesheet URL.
 *
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.2
 *
 * @param string $mce_css CSS path to load in TinyMCE.
 * @return string Filtered CSS path.
 */
function twentytwelve_mce_css( $mce_css ) {
    $font_url = twentytwelve_get_font_url();

    if ( empty( $font_url ) )
        return $mce_css;

    if ( ! empty( $mce_css ) )
        $mce_css .= ',';

    $mce_css .= esc_url_raw( str_replace( ',', '%2C', $font_url ) );

    return $mce_css;
}
add_filter( 'mce_css', 'twentytwelve_mce_css' );

/**
 * Filter the page title.
 *
 * Creates a nicely formatted and more specific title element text
 * for output in head of document, based on current view.
 *
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 *
 * @param string $title Default title text for current view.
 * @param string $sep Optional separator.
 * @return string Filtered title.
 */
function twentytwelve_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
    global $paged, $page;

    if ( is_feed() )
        return $title;

    // Add the site name.
    $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Add the site description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        $title = "$title $sep $site_description";

    // Add a page number if necessary.
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        $title = "$title $sep " . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentytwelve' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'twentytwelve_wp_title', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Filter the page menu arguments.
 *
 * Makes our wp_nav_menu() fallback -- wp_page_menu() -- show a home link.
 *
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
function twentytwelve_page_menu_args( $args ) {
    if ( ! isset( $args['show_home'] ) )
        $args['show_home'] = true;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'twentytwelve_page_menu_args' );

/**
 * Register sidebars.
 *
 * Registers our main widget area and the front page widget areas.
 *
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
function twentytwelve_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'twentytwelve' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'description' => __( 'Appears on posts and pages except the optional Front Page template, which has its own widgets', 'twentytwelve' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</aside>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'First Front Page Widget Area', 'twentytwelve' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-2',
        'description' => __( 'Appears when using the optional Front Page template with a page set as Static Front Page', 'twentytwelve' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</aside>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Second Front Page Widget Area', 'twentytwelve' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-3',
        'description' => __( 'Appears when using the optional Front Page template with a page set as Static Front Page', 'twentytwelve' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</aside>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twentytwelve_widgets_init' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'twentytwelve_content_nav' ) ) :
/**
 * Displays navigation to next/previous pages when applicable.
 *
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
function twentytwelve_content_nav( $html_id ) {
    global $wp_query;

    $html_id = esc_attr( $html_id );

    if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
        <nav id="<?php echo $html_id; ?>" class="navigation" role="navigation">
            <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h3>
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?></div>
        </nav><!-- #<?php echo $html_id; ?> .navigation -->
    <?php endif;
}
endif;

if ( ! function_exists( 'twentytwelve_comment' ) ) :
/**
 * Template for comments and pingbacks.
 *
 * To override this walker in a child theme without modifying the comments template
 * simply create your own twentytwelve_comment(), and that function will be used instead.
 *
 * Used as a callback by wp_list_comments() for displaying the comments.
 *
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 *
 * @return void
 */
function twentytwelve_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    switch ( $comment->comment_type ) :
        case 'pingback' :
        case 'trackback' :
        // Display trackbacks differently than normal comments.
    ?>
    <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
        <p><?php _e( 'Pingback:', 'twentytwelve' ); ?> <?php comment_author_link(); ?> <?php edit_comment_link( __( '(Edit)', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?></p>
    <?php
            break;
        default :
        // Proceed with normal comments.
        global $post;
    ?>
    <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
        <article id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" class="comment">
            <header class="comment-meta comment-author vcard">
                <?php
                    echo get_avatar( $comment, 44 );
                    printf( '<cite><b class="fn">%1$s</b> %2$s</cite>',
                        get_comment_author_link(),
                        // If current post author is also comment author, make it known visually.
                        ( $comment->user_id === $post->post_author ) ? '<span>' . __( 'Post author', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span>' : ''
                    );
                    printf( '<a href="%1$s"><time datetime="%2$s">%3$s</time></a>',
                        esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ),
                        get_comment_time( 'c' ),
                        /* translators: 1: date, 2: time */
                        sprintf( __( '%1$s at %2$s', 'twentytwelve' ), get_comment_date(), get_comment_time() )
                    );
                ?>
            </header><!-- .comment-meta -->

            <?php if ( '0' == $comment->comment_approved ) : ?>
                <p class="comment-awaiting-moderation"><?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <section class="comment-content comment">
                <?php comment_text(); ?>
                <?php edit_comment_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentytwelve' ), '<p class="edit-link">', '</p>' ); ?>
            </section><!-- .comment-content -->

            <div class="reply">
                <?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array( 'reply_text' => __( 'Reply', 'twentytwelve' ), 'after' => ' <span>&darr;</span>', 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ) ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- .reply -->
        </article><!-- #comment-## -->
    <?php
        break;
    endswitch; // end comment_type check
}
endif;

if ( ! function_exists( 'twentytwelve_entry_meta' ) ) :
/**
 * Set up post entry meta.
 *
 * Prints HTML with meta information for current post: categories, tags, permalink, author, and date.
 *
 * Create your own twentytwelve_entry_meta() to override in a child theme.
 *
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 *
 * @return void
 */
function twentytwelve_entry_meta() {
    // Translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma.
    $categories_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'twentytwelve' ) );

    // Translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma.
    $tag_list = get_the_tag_list( '', __( ', ', 'twentytwelve' ) );

    $date = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time></a>',
        esc_url( get_permalink() ),
        esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
        esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_date() )
    );

    $author = sprintf( '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="author">%3$s</a></span>',
        esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
        esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts by %s', 'twentytwelve' ), get_the_author() ) ),
        get_the_author()
    );

    // Translators: 1 is category, 2 is tag, 3 is the date and 4 is the author's name.
    if ( $tag_list ) {
        $utility_text = __( 'This entry was posted in %1$s and tagged %2$s on %3$s<span class="by-author"> by %4$s</span>.', 'twentytwelve' );
    } elseif ( $categories_list ) {
        $utility_text = __( 'This entry was posted in %1$s on %3$s<span class="by-author"> by %4$s</span>.', 'twentytwelve' );
    } else {
        $utility_text = __( 'This entry was posted on %3$s<span class="by-author"> by %4$s</span>.', 'twentytwelve' );
    }

    printf(
        $utility_text,
        $categories_list,
        $tag_list,
        $date,
        $author
    );
}
endif;

/**
 * Extend the default WordPress body classes.
 *
 * Extends the default WordPress body class to denote:
 * 1. Using a full-width layout, when no active widgets in the sidebar
 *    or full-width template.
 * 2. Front Page template: thumbnail in use and number of sidebars for
 *    widget areas.
 * 3. White or empty background color to change the layout and spacing.
 * 4. Custom fonts enabled.
 * 5. Single or multiple authors.
 *
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 *
 * @param array $classes Existing class values.
 * @return array Filtered class values.
 */
function twentytwelve_body_class( $classes ) {
    $background_color = get_background_color();
    $background_image = get_background_image();

    if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) || is_page_template( 'page-templates/full-width.php' ) )
        $classes[] = 'full-width';

    if ( is_page_template( 'page-templates/front-page.php' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'template-front-page';
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
            $classes[] = 'has-post-thumbnail';
        if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) && is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' ) )
            $classes[] = 'two-sidebars';
    }

    if ( empty( $background_image ) ) {
        if ( empty( $background_color ) )
            $classes[] = 'custom-background-empty';
        elseif ( in_array( $background_color, array( 'fff', 'ffffff' ) ) )
            $classes[] = 'custom-background-white';
    }

    // Enable custom font class only if the font CSS is queued to load.
    if ( wp_style_is( 'twentytwelve-fonts', 'queue' ) )
        $classes[] = 'custom-font-enabled';

    if ( ! is_multi_author() )
        $classes[] = 'single-author';

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'twentytwelve_body_class' );

/**
 * Adjust content width in certain contexts.
 *
 * Adjusts content_width value for full-width and single image attachment
 * templates, and when there are no active widgets in the sidebar.
 *
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 *
 * @return void
 */
function twentytwelve_content_width() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'page-templates/full-width.php' ) || is_attachment() || ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) {
        global $content_width;
        $content_width = 960;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'twentytwelve_content_width' );

/**
 * Register postMessage support.
 *
 * Add postMessage support for site title and description for the Customizer.
 *
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 *
 * @param WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize Customizer object.
 * @return void
 */
function twentytwelve_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogname' )->transport         = 'postMessage';
    $wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogdescription' )->transport  = 'postMessage';
    $wp_customize->get_setting( 'header_textcolor' )->transport = 'postMessage';
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'twentytwelve_customize_register' );

/**
 * Enqueue Javascript postMessage handlers for the Customizer.
 *
 * Binds JS handlers to make the Customizer preview reload changes asynchronously.
 *
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 *
 * @return void
 */
function twentytwelve_customize_preview_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwelve-customizer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/theme-customizer.js', array( 'customize-preview' ), '20130301', true );
}
add_action( 'customize_preview_init', 'twentytwelve_customize_preview_js' );
```

below is my CHILD theme functions.php code.

(((***This is where I think I need to use (Function Reference/wp enqueue script) to add an action to make it call that JavaScript and load it only on the home page.)))

```
<?php
/**
 * Twenty Twelve child theme functions file
 *
 */

function tsyoutube_autoplay_script() {

    if(is_front_page()){
        wp_register_script( 'fancybox_auto_open', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/fancybox_auto_open.js', array());
        wp_enqueue_script( 'fancybox_auto_open' );
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tsyoutube_autoplay_script' );
```

Below is info that I have already researched for hours and hours for doing what I need to, but it is vague and I don't know how to make it work.

..

From the WordPress Codex pages:
Function Reference/wp enqueue script,

-Description

Links a script file to the generated page at the right time according to the script dependencies, if the script has not been already included and if all the dependencies have been registered.
You could either link a script with a handle previously registered using the wp_register_script() function, or provide this function with all the parameters necessary to link a script.

**Above is the recommended method of linking JavaScript to a WordPress generated page.**

.
*Thanks everyone for looking :)
I really appreciate any help with this :)
Best regards & thank you,
Tony States*
.

Edited/Added this below 11-24-13

Thanks for the help Gurtfrobe, I can't fit my comment in a comment box? it is to long?

I uploaded my script fancybox_auto_open.js
/www/wp-content/themes/js/fancybox_auto_open.js

this is it below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.fancybox.open({
type:'iframe', 
href: 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/6muHD6bdDYQ?rel=0&border=&autoplay=1',
width: '70%',
height:'70%'})
    $('.various').fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'

    });

});
```

And changed my functions.php code to this below:

```
function tsyoutube_autoplay_script() {

    if(is_front_page()){
        wp_register_script( 'fancybox_auto_open', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/fancybox_auto_open.js', array());
        wp_enqueue_script( 'fancybox_auto_open' );
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tsyoutube_autoplay_script' );
```

Thanks again for all the help :)

Best regards,

Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated my answer based on your initial reply.

Firstly the /plugins folder should be reserved for properly formatted Wordpress plugins. This link should get you started: [Wordpress plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API). I won't go into here as it's a bit of tangent.

Therefore for this exercise I'm going to pretend your JS file is in your theme directory in a folder called 'js'. Make sure that you remove the opening and closing script tags in your JS file.

Then in your functions.php copy/paste the following:

```
function abc_setup_scripts() {

    if(is_front_page()){
        wp_register_script( 'fancybox_auto_open', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/fancybox.auto.open.js', array());
        wp_enqueue_script( 'fancybox_auto_open' );
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'abc_setup_scripts' );
```

The first part:

```
function abc_setup_scripts() {
```

Creates a new function. It's important to ensure your function's name doesn't clash with another function from a third party plugin etc so we add something unique to the start - in this case 'abc_'. If your project is called "Tony's Window Cleaning" for example you might use 'twc_' to prefix all the functions you write yourself.

Then we check to see if we're on the page you nominated as your Wordpress front page under Settings > Reading with this line:

```
if(is_front_page()){
```

If your front page isn't set this way then the function won't run. Ideally you should set it this way as that's how Wordpress is designed to work.

Then, assuming we are on the front page, our function will run and Wordpress be notified of our script we want to load into the HTML Head. Notice I changed 'fancybox.auto.open' to 'fancybox_auto_open'. It's best to use underscores to avoid weird bugs.

The bit that says:

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
```

Is a handy Wordpress function that prints out the path to your active theme folder's directory. If you end up moving your script into the plugins folder, you'll need to change this line. See this page on what to use instead: [Plugins URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url)

See how you go with that.

Comment: Thanks Gurtfrobe, I dont understand the "posting and commenting" user interface here, I tried adding my comment here with what I did and it was of course to long! please see my edits to the bottom of my original post!

Comment: OK Gurtfrobe, I think I did everything you suggested, I removed open and close javascript tags and put it in /wordpress/themes/js/ folder, I changed all the names and references to it to: 'fancybox_auto_open' next ? for this code: `if(is_front_page()){` should that literally be just that or should it be what my home page is? sorry for stupid ?'s I am a rookie! I edited and added my new code for my child functions.php file above:  but I am still not successful at auto launching my video on my wordpress home page load. any other suggestions? really appreciate your time helping me Gurtfrobe :)

Comment: Does my java-script file look right? the names of everything correct?

Comment: Hi Tony, could you confirm the JS file is in **/wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/js/**? I'll have a look through the rest this evening.

Comment: yes sir it is in my /www/wp-content/themes/ts-child-theme/js - and just to make sure because you didnt specify if I needed it in my parent or child theme I put it in my parent and child theme js folder and still no luck. I just dont know what it could be? - I can upload screenshots and or any code that you want to see on the home page of tonystates.com if you need me to OK, just tell me what you need and I will do it. I can zip up everything, or anything, just say the word!!! --Many thanks again Gurtfrobe, Tony :))

Comment: Hi Tony, could you Zip up the child theme folder and stick it on a public dropbox link for me to download? Once I have it I'll let you know so you can take the link down. Thanks.

Comment: WoHoooooo it works!!! I went into the backend of my wordpress site and into themes and there was an error in my child theme template and when I fixed it the autoplay for the video worked perfect! many thanks again Gurtfrobe :) sorry it took me so long to figure it out. your code is and instructions are perfect, great job to you :)